# Customize validation error message depending on the context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to have different error messages for the same model depending on the form's context and location.

For the `User` model which validates presence of `first_name`:

- In the back-office page it is OK to have the validation message "First name can't be blank"
- In the registration page the message should be "Please type your first name"

I am looking for a clean and best-practice oriented solution, because I would like not to hack with view helper and such.

Any hint appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [validate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) method in `User` model . Something like this

```
validate do |user|
 if user.first_name.blank? && user.id.blank? 
   # id blank means the user is in registration page as he is new user. 
   user.errors.add(:base, "Please type your first name")
 elsif user.first_name.blank?
   user.errors.add(:base, "First name can't be blank")
 end
end
```

Comment: Good thought, but that's not really good-practice as it bypass rails form validation. Additionally the `create` action from the back-office would display the wrong error message.

Comment: haaha, that's too simple, just add error in `base`. Updated the code. Try it. I guess that is most optimal way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I really don't want to bypass rails validation at it source by using validate as you suggest. I prefer to look for a message substitution solution

Answer (score 1):

May be using `hidden_field` and `attr_accessor`, I hope you can achieve what you want,

## Form 1:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :check_form, :value => true %>
```

## Form 2:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :check_form, :value => false %>
```

You need to pass `check_form` value also to the model.

## Model:

```
attr_accessor :check_form
validates_presence_of :first_name, :if => :check_form_is_true?, :message => "First Name can't be blank"
validates_presence_of :first_name, :unless => :check_form_is_true? //here you need to use i18n oriented translation to show the custom error message

private
def check_form_is_true?
  check_form == true
end
```

## config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        first_name: ""
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            first_name:
              blank: "Please type your first name"
```

Hope it helps :)